# (C) N x N Array of zeros

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization, declaration

I am new to C and would like to create a N x N matrix of zeros (i.e., every element is zero). N is an integer.

Using MATLAB I managed to generate such an array using the code:
**Array = zeros(N);**

However, in C, how would we generate such an array with minimal lines of code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are several ways to do that i C. The best way depends on your use case. For instance the value of N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write

```
T matrix[N][N] = { 0 };
```

where `T` is some type specifier as for example `int`.

Such an initialization is allowed if N is an integer constant expression.

Otherwise you need to write

```
#include <string.h>

//...

T matrix[N][N];
memset( matrix, 0, sizeof( matrix ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate the memory using the [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) function which usually allocates memory on the heap (which is good if `N` is *large*):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
//...
int(*dyn)[N] = calloc(N, sizeof *dyn);
// use dyn
free(dyn);
```